# video record and playback at same time using DirectShow

Tags: c#, c++, video, directshow, directshow.net

I should develop an application that records and plays recorded video while recording continues (without stopping graph). I know how to use and develop using DirectShow but I need architecture of my graph. What filters should I use?

I did it with raw video using DirectShow and [SampleGrabber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I should compress video and I have no idea how to do it in compressed video file (which is not closed, because recording continues).

I think MPEG-2 recording is the best for my application but please guide me about filters I should use.

Thanks

Comment: It's been long since I have done any DShow developing but there are filters that take one input and generate N copies of that input that can be fed to different processing (display + record)

Comment: I know how to display and record. I use Smart Tee filter for that but what if I need video of 10 seconds ago?

Comment: Few of the file formats are compatible with "playback while still recording", perhaps MPEG-2 TS and maybe ASF only. to reliably address this problem you need to record into custom format where you can read data without relying on file closed, finalized and flushed.

Comment: MPEG-2 is compatible with playback still recording (I tested it a lot. It works). So I want to use MPEG-2 not other formats

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [StreamBufferEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663613%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Recording a file and watching it at the same time is a little bit problematic, because the Demuxer needs to reparse the written file, to know about the new parts. I have never seen an demuxer doing this.

The other big problem is the file-locking! The DirectShow filewriter and most other similar filters lock the file for the writing. So no other process can open the file for reading.

You are searching for a TimeShift system. There are some thirt-party SDK for this. But it can also be implemented with own DirectShow Filters, but you will need a lot of time and knowledge for this. I know it's possible because I have done it in the videoplayer from my company ([utilius fairplay 5](http://www.ccc-software.de/en/sport/sportsoftware/produkte/utilius-fairPLAY5.php)).

Comment: MPEG-2 video works this way. I start recording from a camera and save MPEG-2 in a file using GraphEdit, then open VLC and browse recording file. VLC plays video. It's like watching recorded video 5 seconds later. It's because VLC grants read access. So, if VLC can read, I can read too. Now I'm working on MPEG-2 file reading (it's very complex stuff using DirectShow :| )

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I worked on that issue for weeks,  SBE does not work well in H264 mux in transport
I came up with a solution , let me share

First , the encoder need to have small GOP , like 15 , not 150, otherwise the sync will take time and it will seen as a big hang.

The idea is to create directshow filter , start from Live source filter
(https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/158053/DirectShow-Filters-Development-Part-2-Live-Source)

Modified the filter , not to enter the frame from external program.

add winsock2 , for UDP binding  , or multicast group.
Start receive the data from live source and sample it out to the output pin.

Suggest always to use Elecard SDk for setup.
On the sender you can use nw renderer but there you cannot change the encoder GOP
so open graph edit and build the sender graph
desktop capture->encoder->mux->nwrenderer.

Your new filter should know to receive the data and display it on screen

once you have that working you can than continue add the timeshift capabilities into your filter.

Allocate a very big buffer , 200 mega to 1 giga , up to you( on ram ofcourse) 
the same data that you send to the output pin , copy it into that buffer, make it circular with rd and wr indexes.

You need to add interface to your filter, functions like
1. GoLive
2.SetSeekPoint

The way i did it is the following
I created a callback from the filter into the host ( c# ) that send the time and the wr pointer every 1 second or more( depends on the accurate i need)
In the host i created a list of those two information.
Now in c# i have the list of the wr pointer and its time.
easy to search and set the RD pointer back to the filter.

The filter have two modes than:
1. in live it send the current received data
2. in seek it send the data from the big buffer , following the rd pointer.

Hope it understood.