# Real-time movie building from bitmaps

Tags: c#, video-capture, movie, mov

I need an advice how to save captured frames in bitmap format into real-time groving movie.
I need to create a movie file (*.mov* if possible) what will groving during capturing and can be used by other processes.

If its possible I would like to use an intra-frame codec.

Additional info: Im capturing from a BlackMagic DeckLink Quad using BlackMagic SDK in .net c#.

Comment: What do you mean by "realtime"? And what have you tried?

Comment: I mean that post-processing is not ok for me. Post-processing would be  first collecting the frames and after that create the movie from them. I need to create the movie and during capturing the frames simultaneously add them to the movie.

Comment: Either way you are going to add frames one by one. So it doesnt really matter when you do it (after you recieve all images or as you reciev every image). There are plenty of manuals on how to do that.

Comment: I need to access and work with (watch) the movie during the building. That is not possible by post-processing. That`s why I need to build it real time.
Could you recommend some of the mentioned manuals please?

Comment: Well, ability to watch video while writing it is a huge complication. Your best bet is to dig into `DirectShow`. It can do it, but it is not going to be an easy task. You should try to simply write video file first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423574/video-record-and-playback-at-same-time-using-directshow here is a similar question. There is no particualar answer, but it contains some food for thought